# Can I add transparency to a joined object?

Tags: materials, objects, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I used the 'join' function to make a large object (made up of many smaller objects with their own materials)

Now I want to do a global transparency although the only way I can find so far is to go into each object and adjust the alpha blend manually for each one. Surely there's a better way!?

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to batch edit the materials, but if you don't have many reflections, you could try using compositing. If you add the (large) object to its own view layer you can mix it back with the original and change the factor to change its "transparency."

Comment: Thanks Tim. Some of the materials do have reflections, although (on reflection) I guess I could just render the object as it's own layer and use the opacity setting in premiere..